# How do I open .blend files AND activate scripts via code?

Tags: scripting, external-applications

I want to make a program, in Python or C++ likely, to carry out batch script functions across multiple .blend files. So how do I open a .blend file and have it auto-run a script (the script is already in the .blend file), without having to do anything manually?

Edit: I am using this command line: `Marie.blend --python test.py`

I am using this script (test.py):

```py
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]

scn.frame_end = 10
```

The script works when run 'normally', but when using the command line, the file just opens and the script is ignored. (Auto.run has already been enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [command line arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) in the manual.  The [python options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) sections shows how to invoke a python command at run time.  You can also register scripts to run at start time.  See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182972/how-could-i-compile-and-update-dependencies-automatically) for details.

Two important notes, uncovered from our discussion:

1. On systems like windows, where you can invoke Blender from the command line by naming the blend file (ie `> Marie.blend`) the `--python` argument will be ignored.  On such systems you must invoke Blender by name and the `--python` argument must go before the blend file name.
2. Scripts invoked at startup are run before everything is initialized.  You need to wait for initialization before your script will work.  I'll update the answer later with a technique for that.

Comment: I never used command line arguments in coding. How would you send a certain command line to Blender from another program, say, a C++ program?

Comment: That would depend on the OS.  In Unix-like systems you might call `system`. The [system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) man page would explain the arguments.  There's something similar for Windows.

Comment: ARGH How do I do this?? I got this, it opens the file but does not run the script:
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
filepath = '"Marie.blend" --python Text'
os.system(filepath)

Comment: Sorry, the comments will not let me do line breaks...

Comment: Is the script an external file or is it a text block inside the blender file?  For an external file you need to pass `system` the equivalent of `blender --python filename.py` but for a text block use `blender --python-text textname`  I suggest getting the command to work properly from the command line first; and then when you're sure it works write the C++ code to invoke `system`.  Also, remember that you have to have 'autorun' enabled in preferences to be able to run scripts.

Comment: Marie.blend --python test.py will not work for me. It opens the Marie.blend file but does not run the script. I tried an internal script, too, with Marie.blend --python-text Text but still nothing happened. The script does not run. Auto-run is enabled in settings.

Comment: Do you have the python in a separate file or is it in a text in the blend file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134157/discussion-between-henry-stone-and-marty-fouts).